# Can "the elderly" be used for some specific old people?

Tags: word-usage

I wonder if I can use "the elderly", by which I mean old people, to refer to a specific group of old people. For example:

> The elderly with death anxiety

Is this acceptable? Or should I use something like *old people with death anxiety* instead?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase *the elderly* is absolutely acceptable. In fact, I'd say, given your two options, it's preferred.

The term *old people* can be interpreted as impolite or disrepectful, especially in more contemorary usages.

If *the elderly* seems too formal for your particular use, I'd recommend *older people* instead of *old people*; that softer wording seems more thoughtful and less inconsiderate:

> *older people with death anxiety*

Interesting Ngram [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=old+people+who%2Celderly+people+who%2Colder+people+who&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3), if you care to look. It shows how *older* and *elderly* began to gain traction in the 1970s and *old people* began to dip about about decade later:

[image]

That said, you've given a very small sample of text, so it's hard to say for sure. Are you making a speech, writing a report, or talking among friends? And what is the surrounding context?

I ask those questions because it *is* possible to use "old people" without sounding impolite. However, safer alternatives are available.

I managed to find one book that poked fun at this in a humorous way (even the title of the book reveals how this is intended to be humorous):

> *The only way we can remember how things used to be is by going to museums. Fortunately, we have the Old People. The Old People are our museums*.
>
> *The Old People who hate being called Old People and prefer to be called Elders, Retirees, or Wise Ones still know how to display the full panoply of emotions*...
> <sub>Source: ***The Get-Over-Yourself Self-Help Book and Other Essays: The Collected Works of a Misunderstood Curmudgeon***</sub>
> <sup>by Sylvia Shawcross</sup>

Comment: thanks. Regarding question's purpose, is "the" a must-be part of elderly?

Comment: If you use _elderly_ as an adjective, no: _"Many elderly people experience death anxiety."_ However, if you use the phrase _the elderly_ to refer the demographic, then, yes, you need to include the "the": _"Many of the elderly experience death anxiety."_ Check out [Meaning 10](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/the).